# Fetch frames from Mjpeg stream in php

Tags: php, frame, mjpeg

I'm trying to fetch frames from an Mjpeg stream in PHP. I've tried file read to read file and then on the basis on headers fetch frames. But I'm not able to do it.
I'm able to see headers present in file but when using exif_read_data to find if the headers exist, it shows there are no headers.
My code to fetch frame is:

```
function grab_frame($url) {
 $f = fopen($url, 'r'); //6,168
 if($f) {
    $r = null;
    while(substr_count($r, "Content-Length")!= 5){ 
        $r.= fread($f,40000000);            
        $start = strpos($img,'F1');
        $end   = strpos($img,'F2');
       $frame  = substr($r, $start, $end);
    }   
    fclose($f);
    return $frame; 
 }
}
```

I want to use content-length header to find the frame length and then fetch the whole frame data and then loop again to find next frame.

Answer (score 5):

read mjpeg raw until complete.

```
<?php

$camurl="http://admin:pazz@192.168.137.252:80/getimage"; // Mjpeg URL

$f = fopen($camurl, "r");
$r = "";

if($f) {
    // unless 1 frame raw read.
    while (substr_count($r, "\xFF\xD8")<2) $r.=fread($f, 8192);
}

// clip frame out raw
$start = strpos($r, "\xFF\xD8");
$end = strpos($r, "\xFF\xD9", $start)+2;
$frame = substr($r, $start, $end-$start);

Header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $frame;

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The code here might help you. It will produce a JPEG snapshot from an MJPEG stream. You will need to change $boundary to match the boundary name found in your mjpeg stream. You should be able to modify the code to capture multiple frames.

(from https://gist.github.com/megasaturnv/81279fca49f2f34b42e77815c9bb1eb8 . code generates image in img tag at https://gist.github.com/megasaturnv/35578337662acd28e0bcd2946a4b069e)

```
<?php
//Megasaturnv 2018-01-12
$camurl="http://192.168.1.100:8081/";                           // Mjpeg URL
//$camurl="http://username:password@192.168.1.100:8081/"        // HTTP Auth mjpeg URL (optional)
$boundary="--BoundaryString";                                   // $boundary = The boundary string between jpegs in an mjpeg stream
//NOTE: $boundary changes between mjpeg stream providers. For example, https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion uses '--BoundaryString'. https://github.com/ZoneMinder/ZoneMinder uses '--ZoneMinderFrame'. To find out $boundary for your stream you will need to save 1 or more frames of the mjpeg and open it with a text editor. --<boundary string> should be visible on the first line
$f = fopen($camurl, "r");                                       // Open mjpeg url as $f in readonly mode
$r = "";                                                        // Set $r to blank variable

if($f) {
    while (substr_count($r,"Content-Length") < 2)               // While the number of times "Content-Length" appears in $r is less than 2
        $r.=fread($f, 16384);                                   // Append 16384 bytes of $f to $r

    $start = strpos("$r", $boundary);                           // $start is set to the position of the first occurrence of '$boundary' in $r
    $end = strpos("$r", $boundary, $start + strlen($boundary)); // $end is essentially set to the position of the second occurrence of '$boundary' in $r. I use $start + strlen($boundary) to offset the start position and skip the first occurrence
    $boundaryAndFrame = substr("$r", $start, $end - $start);    // $boundaryAndframe is set to the string in $r starting at position $start and with a length of ($end - $start)

    $pattern="/(Content-Length:\s*\d*\r\n\r\n)([\s\S]*)/";      // Use regex to search for '(Content-Length:       90777\r\n\r\n)(<jpeg image data>)
    preg_match_all($pattern, $boundaryAndFrame, $matches);      // Search for regex matches in $boundaryAndFrame
    $frame = $matches[2][0];                                    // $frame is set to the second regex character group (in this case, <jpeg image data>)
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");                         // Set header for jpeg image
    echo $frame;                                                // Echo the jpeg image data
} else {
    echo "Error, cannot open URL";                              // Error message if $camurl cannot be opened
}

fclose($f);                                                     // Close the url
?>
```

Comment: Works flawlessly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My solution to analise frame

```
function readPixel($url, $x, $y, $callback)
{
    $loop = 0;
    //Megasaturnv 2018-01-12
    // Mjpeg URL
    $camurl = $url;
    //$camurl="http://username:password@192.168.1.100:8081/"        // HTTP Auth mjpeg URL (optional)
    $boundary="--BoundaryString";                                   // $boundary = The boundary string between jpegs in an mjpeg stream
    //NOTE: $boundary changes between mjpeg stream providers. For example, https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion uses '--BoundaryString'. https://github.com/ZoneMinder/ZoneMinder uses '--ZoneMinderFrame'. To find out $boundary for your stream you will need to save 1 or more frames of the mjpeg and open it with a text editor. --<boundary string> should be visible on the first line
    $f = fopen($camurl, "r");                                       // Open mjpeg url as $f in readonly mode
    $r = "";                                                        // Set $r to blank variable

    if($f) {
        while (true){
        $r.=fread($f, 50000);

        $startsearch = strpos($r, "Content-Length: ");
        if($startsearch!==false){
            $r = substr($r, $startsearch+16);

            $index=0;
            $length = "";
            while(true){
                $char = substr($r, $index, 1);
                $index++;

                if(is_numeric($char)){
                    $length.= $char;
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }

            $r = substr($r, strlen($length)+4);
            $totalbytes = $length-0;
            $havebytes=strlen($r);
            $remain = $totalbytes-$havebytes;

            //echo "Length:$length\n";
            //echo "Stream:$r\n";   
            //echo "HaveBytes $havebytes totalbytes: $totalbytes, Remain: $remain\n";

            while($havebytes < $totalbytes){
                $r .=fread($f, $totalbytes-$havebytes);
                $havebytes = strlen($r);
            }

            //save/debug image
            //file_put_contents("test.jpg", $r);

            $im = imagecreatefromstring($r);

            //test if image is valid
            //$valid = ($im != FALSE);
            //echo ($valid?"VALID":"INVALID")."\n";
            //echo imagesx($im).'x'.imagesy($im) ."\n";

            $rgb = imagecolorat ($im, $x, $y);

            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;       

            imagedestroy($im);
            $loop++;

            if($callback($r,$g,$b, $loop)){
                echo "TEST colors: $r $g $b\n";
            }else{
                fclose($f);
                return true;
            }

            $r="";
        }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error, cannot open URL"; // Error message if $camurl cannot be opened
    }

    fclose($f); // Close the url
}
```